# union intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been looking into set theory and came across this

$$|A| + |B| \geq |A\cap B| + |A\cup B|
$$

By looking at this and drawing it out I feel like the statement holds. could someone confirm this and if possible show me a proof as to why it holds?

Comment: What are $a,b$?

Comment: I wonder if he means $|A| + |B| \geq |A\cap B| + |A\cup B|$?

Comment: two arbitrary sets... usually examples are given of 2 circles with an intersection

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $\{x+y, x \in A \cap B, y \in A\cup B\} \subset \{x+y, x\in A , y \in B\}$ ?

Comment: @stity nope, im trying to show that two sets added together are greater than or equal to the intersection + union of both sets ... i.e. lets say $a:= \{1,2,3,4\}, b:=\{3,4,5\} \Rightarrow 7 \geq 2+3$

Comment: I have made an edit to my original post, I meant the size of the sets

Comment: "a:={1,2,3,4},b:={3,4,5}⇒7≥2+3"  But the size of the union *isn't* 3.  It is 5.  You have |a| + |b| = 4 + 3 = 7 = 2 + 5 = |a $\cap$ b| + |a $\cup$ b|.  Equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

You even have the equality : $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me?

Comment: When counting the number of elements in $A \cup B$, count the number of element in A and B and simply substract the number of elements that are in A and in B to avoid counting them twice

Comment: I think you should have $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - 2|A \cap B|
$ instead?

Comment: @smith No because you want to count them once no not all

Comment: ohhhh of course it makes sense now! so now would I apply your equation in order to help me prove the above?

Comment: $$|A|+|B| = |A \cup B| + |A \cap B|$$ and therefore you have $$|A|+|B| \ge |A \cup B| + |A \cap B|$$

Answer (score 1):

In [your example in comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568209/union-intersection/1568249#comment3192811_1568209) it seems to me you have gotten the numbers wrong. The sum of the sizes is $|A|+|B|=4+3=7$. The size of the intersection is $|A\cap B|=|\{3,4\}|=2$. The size of the union is $|A\cup B|=|\{1,2,3,4,5\}|=5$. So we have $4+3=7=2+5$.

Indeed, equality holds in any case. stity's answer should give you a hand in proving that. Once you accept that equality, the equality I state you should try to prove instead of your inequality should become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

For finite sets:

Basic common sense:  If X and Y are disjoint (i.e. X $\cap$ Y = $\emptyset$).  Than |X $\cup$ Y| = |X| + |Y|.  This should be obvious.  X has |X| elements and Y has |Y| different elements and X $\cup$ Y is precisely the the set containing all the elements of X and all the elements of why.

Let |A| = a, |B| = b, and |A $\cap$ B| = m.  Let A - (A $\cap$ B) = {a $\in$ A| a $\notin$ A $\cap$ B}.  A, and  A - (A $\cap$ B) are disjoint and ( A - (A $\cap$ B)) $\cup$ (A $\cap$ B).  So  A - (A $\cap$ B) = a - m.

Likewise  B - (A $\cap$ B) = b -m.

Then A $\cup$ B = ( A - (A $\cap$ B)) $\cup$ (A $\cap$ B) $\cup$ (B - (A $\cap$ B)).  This is a union of 3 disjoint sets so

|A $\cup$ B| = (a - m) + (m) + (b -m) = a + b -m = |A| + |B| - |A $\cap$ B| and

So |A| + |B| =|A $\cup$ B| + |A $\cap$ B|.